# Any updates on Service fabric mesh limitations

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-service-fabric-mesh

Do we have any updated on Service fabric limitations which are mentioned in the below link?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-service-fabric-mesh-is-now-in-public-preview/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the limitations are described in the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-faq) in the docs, it should have the most recent information when these limitations are changed, the last update is as old as the blog post you linked.

The other source of information is the [github issues list](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-mesh-preview/issues)

And the Twitter [@servicefabric](https://twitter.com/servicefabric)

And then, the [SF blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/)

Technically, not many updates has been released since then, 
I've heard they are currently focused on next Conference, probably they will have more updates after that.

Comment: A new update has been released today: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/2018/12/04/service-fabric-mesh-preview-refresh-release/